# How to convert a void* to a type that can be used in C#? Interoperability between C DLL and C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, void-pointers

I am a C/C++ programmer, but I was asked to update a program that was written in C# to communicate with a device. My knowledge of C# is very basic.

The previous version was totally written in C#, but now the API that in fact access the device was changed to C. I found out that I can import the C function APIs by using:

```
[DllImport("myapi.dll")]
public static extern int myfunct( 
                                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpDeviceName,
                                 IntPtr hpDevice);
```

In C this function prototype is:

```
int myFunct( LPTStr lpDeviceName, HANDLE* hpDevice );
```

Where HANDLE is defined as :

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

However this function does not work as expected. In fact, in the C# code call what kind of type I should declare and pass to the C# method?

Thanks for the help and sorry for any stupid question.

Comment: That's the right way of marshalling a HANDLE type to a CLR type.  There must be something else wrong with your code.  Can you give us more detail?

Comment: I agree with ville.  Show where you're getting the `hpDevice` you pass.  In general, I would expect it to come from another function in the same library.

Comment: I tried this

 public IntPtr myHANDLE = new IntPtr();

Comment: Use IntPtr.Zero for a default value. In general though, you wouldn't set your handles manually - they would be returned by some other function which creates the handle to begin with. Unless this is the function which sets the handle, in which case, pass `ref IntPtr` as the type.

Comment: By the way, I made it work on C while testing the API. I had to declare it simply as HANDLE myHandle and pass it to the function as a pointer like myfunc(&myHandle)

Comment: @Mark, I think you're right about `ref`.  That fits zlogdan's C code, and it's probably why it takes a pointer-to-HANDLE, when `HANDLE` is already pointer-to-void.

Comment: I tested it with IntPtr myHandle and passed it like: myfunct(myHandle), the compiler accepts it but the function fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing IntPtr instead of ref IntPtr, the definition should look like this:

```
[DllImport("myapi.dll")]
public static extern int myfunct( 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpDeviceName,
    ref IntPtr hpDevice);
```

Comment: In fact your solution was partially correct, I learned it in another forum that it is better to pass a StringBuilder instead of Marshalling a LPTStr.

Comment: This works just used a Stringbuilder instead of a string Marshalled that way.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is the wrong way of marshalling `HANDLE *`. It'll work, but not be reliable in the face of exceptions.

The function you posted looks like an object creation function (it's treating `hpDevice` as an output parameter, and returning an `int` status result).

The correct way to marshal it depends on exactly what type of object it's creating and how it is closed. Assuming that the `HANDLE` is closed by calling `CloseHandle` (which is true for most *but not all* `HANDLE` objects), then you can probably use one of the types that inherits from [`SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid.aspx). For example, if the object is a registry key, then use [`SafeRegistryHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.saferegistryhandle.aspx); if it's a file, then use [`SafeFileHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.aspx).

If it's some type for which there isn't an existing safe handle type (but does use `CloseHandle` to close it), then you'll have to define your own safe handle type derived from `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid`. If it's some type that doesn't use `CloseHandle` to close it, then you'll have to define your own safe handle type derived from `SafeHandle`.

Once you have determined the correct `SafeHandle`-derived type, then you can use it in the function call (using `SafeFileHandle` as an example):

```
[DllImport("myapi.dll")]
public static extern int myFunct(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpDeviceName,
    out SafeFileHandle hpDevice);
```

Comment: I have tried this and yet it compiles the result is not Ok. This HANDLE is for a device that is connected to the serial port and when I wrote the application in C, I've just declared it as "HANDLE myHandle" and pass its address to the function and inside the API, this HANDLE was initialized . I also have tried to use ref InPtr without any luck as well.

Comment: Is the HANDLE the serial port, or is it used as an opaque handle to a "device" *connected* to the serial port? `SafeFileHandle` could be used only if the HANDLE is the serial port itself, not an opaque device handle. Another thing to check is a [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) mismatch: the C++ default is `cdecl` and the C# default is `stdcall`.

Comment: I have no means to know how this handle is used, the third party API simply says they "wrap either serial or USB connections" when this function is called. As I said, I made a test before trying to integrate this on the C# project and all I needed to do was to declare a handle as in HANDLE h and pass its address to the function, it just returned the proper one without complaints.

Comment: Well, C# is more type-safe than that. That's why it's not as simple. :)  Even if you don't know what the `HANDLE` refers to, you should be able to know how it is "closed." What function do you have to call to close the handles?

Comment: DWORD WINAPI McpClose (HANDLE  hDevice);

Comment: In this case, you need to use your own `SafeHandle`-derived type. `SafeFileHandle` will not work.

Comment: Hi, the part of the HANDLE was correct man. Just like Yakeen said, It was needed only a IntPtr hpDevice declaration. The part that was not working as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpDeviceName,
this should be StringBuilder lpDeviceName and that1s why it was not working.

Comment: "It'll work, but not be reliable in the face of exceptions." (me)

Comment: I'm experimenting with a small C++ dll, that I call into. Do I need to create a C++ class/struct that matches my SafeHandle class and return it, or do I just return a `BYTE*, bool*, void*` pointer from the C++. In essence, what special handling would the C++ side of the equation need when I call `[DllImport("my.dll")] static extern MySafeHandle GetMyHandle();`

Comment: Just return a pointer. `SafeHandle` is a pointer.